# Select in a mysql table with self-join relationship

Tags: mysql, group-by, self-join

I am not very familiar with the self-join relationships but i wanted to know if it is possible, performing a SELECT, to show the products in relation to other products directly under the product referenced, in this table mysql

[image]

Sample data:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

I tried several queries but I only get a field with the list, for example, of related products in the row itself:

```
select p1.idP, p1.name, group_concat(p2.idP) 
from prodotti p1
left join prodotti p2 on p1.idP = p2.prodotti_idP
group by p1.idP;
```

I would like to show the records connected to others ONLY directly under the "parent" product

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72ffbcf/4)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without using any "Self Join". A conditional `ORDER BY` using `CASE .. WHEN` expressions would work. If `prodotti_idP` is `null`, it basically means that it is a parent product. So we can simply sort it by its `idP` value; otherwise we will use its parent id (`prodotti_idP`) to sort upon. A second level sorting has to be done on `idP` value.

```
select idP, name, prodotti_idP
from prodotti 
order by 
  case when prodotti_idP is null then idP
       else prodotti_idp
  end, 
  idP
```

**SQL Fiddle Demo**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72ffbcf/6